# <DIV> moving down on Window Resize

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my right_section div. When I resize the browser window, it stays on the right side, but when I hit a certain size it drops down below everything else and continues to compress scrunching up the text within.

How can I get right_section to stay in place when I **resize a browser window** ?

**CSS:**

```
    #wrapper {
        background-color: #fff;
        margin: 80px auto auto auto;
        max-width: 1300px;
        border: 2px solid #5B5B5B;
        padding: 20px;
        box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.7);
        border-radius: 20px;
    }

    #container {
        background-color: #fff;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    #header {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #logoarea {
        position: absolute;
        top: 3%;
        left: 46%;
    }

        #logoarea img {
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 4px solid rgba(155,155,155,0.7);
        }

    #header {
        margin: 0;
    }

        #header h1 {
            margin: 0;
            text-align: left;
            font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Gotham, sans-serif;
            font-size: 22px;
            color: #000000;
            padding: 1%;
            text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
        }

    nav {
        margin: 0;
        width: 290px;
        float: left;
    }

    #right_section {
        margin: 0px 0 0 6px;
        width: 74%;
        float: right;
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
        overflow: relative;
    }

        #right_section p {
            padding: 20px;
        }

    #footer {
        margin: 0;
    }

        #footer p {
            margin: 0;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Gotham, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            padding: 2% 0%;
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<!--Start Wrapper-->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!--Start Container-->
            <div id="container">
                <!--Start logoarea-->
                    <div id="logoarea">
                        ...
                    </div>
                <!--End logoarea-->
                <!--Start header-->
                    <div id="header">
                    ...
                    </div>
                <!--End header-->
                <!--Start Nav-->
                    <nav>
                    ...
                    </nav>

                   <div id="right_section">

                   </div>

            </div>
            <!--End container-->
      </div>
      <!--End wrapper-->
</body>
```

Thanks for any and all help in advance.

Comment: Maybe try to give right section width in percent?

Comment: It already has: width: 74%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `nav{ margin:0; width:290px; float:left;  }` to  `nav{ margin:0; width:26%; float:left;  }`

change `#right_section {margin: 0px 0 0 6px;}` to `#right_section {margin: 0px 0 0 0px;}`

Comment: Almost :) This worked in keeping the right_section from jumping down the page on resize. Now if I resize enough it goes right over top of the nav section ... how do I make it stop at a certain point and keep nav and right_section fully visible without overlapping ?

Comment: add css  min-width:300px   to #wrapper. You might adjust the value to 200px or 400px, depends on how long your nav is

Comment: doesn't appear to help at all ... with any value

Comment: add min-width:300px to #container

Comment: min-width:1000px; for container seems to have the desired effect ... on most pages :)

Comment: Then it is not a good idea for mobile device, 1000px is too long, you might need to add some media queries for mobile device

Comment: once last question: when I resize, my background image is shrinking upwards .. how do I keep that in place nicely ? (I haven't tackled mobile devices yet, but it is/will be an issue for sure.) I'm not overly handy with CSS yet .... php/java are my thang.

Comment: Can't see your background, but you can try background-size:cover or background-attachment: fixed;

Comment: body{ background:url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat fixed; background-size:100% !important;}

Comment: cover works perfect. Thanks for all the help. Now to find someone to fix all of my CSS up :)

Comment: Good to hear it works. could you mark this as answer? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the css property

```
 white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: white-space doesn't work. It simply throws the text in right_section in a straight line.

Comment: You may use min-width on #container or
position:absolute; on #right_section and right:0 + position:relative on #container

Answer (score 0):

I think the main part of the problem is the math:

1. SHELL (aka #wrapper): `max-width: 1300px;`
2. LEFT SIDE (aka nav): `width: 290px;`
3. RIGHT SIDE: `margin: 0px 0 0 6px;` + `width: 74%;`

At a certain point, 290px is greater than (1300px minus (74% plus 6px));

So two things.
1. Make the left side a percentage: `width:24%;`
2. But that won't work without compensating for the `margin`, so change the right side to `margin: 0px 0 0 6px;` + `width: calc(74% - 6px);`

I don't know the browsers you need to support, but you should reference [canIUse for calc()](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

All that being said, this is a great example to use `display:flex;` with!
[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/Bushwazi/pen/MwbLYW)

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="logoarea">LOGO AREA</div>
    <div id="header">HEADER</div>
    <nav>MAIN NAVIGATION</nav>
    <div id="right_section">RIGHT SECTION</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 80px auto auto auto;
  max-width: 1300px;
  width:100%; // <== to always fill parent
  border: 2px solid #5B5B5B;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.7);
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-sizing:border-box; // <== puts the padding inside the box
}
#container {
  background-color: #fff;
  display:flex; // <== flex ftw
  flex-wrap:wrap; // <== wrap that flex
}
#logoarea {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  left: 46%;
}
#header {
  margin: 0;
  width:100%; // <== full width. I assume this was the goal
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.1); // <== just to see the box
  text-align center; // again, an assumption
}
nav {
  width: 26%;
  background: rgba(0,255,0,0.1); // <== just to see the box
}
#right_section {
  margin: 0px 0 0 6px;
  width: calc(74% - 6px); // <== use calc to compensate for the margin
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.1); // <== just to see the box
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Jason ... I'll take some time and read up on this and give it a try. (quick cut and paste messed it all up :) )